# Best practice to return and catch value from jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine something like bellow:

```
$('selector').on('change', function () {
    return 'something'; 
});
```

Is this good choice to return the value? And then how to catch that value after event complete.

Comment: You should read the documentation of on... especially the part about what happens when the event handler returns false.

Comment: @Denys Séguret ok thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this good choice to return the value?

No...

> And then how to catch that value after event complete.

...Because you cannot get the value you return, as you're returning from the anonymous function which is not reachable from any other place in your code. The `return` statement in the event handler is expected to be a boolean value which indicates whether `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()` should run on the event. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler) for more information.

If you need perform another action after an event handler has been executed either call it as a function and pass the value you require, or put the values in a variable that's in scope of the required logic.

Comment: And also: there's some consequence of returning some value from an event handler

Comment: Indeed, added a note about that

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thank you for your answer